# Como fazer upload de arquivos Angular js

Tags: angularjs, multiple-file-upload

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

queria saber agora como faço para pega e enviar o arquivo para url que desejo fazer o upload.

[image]

Comment: ng-file-upload: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Comment: Se você entende Inglês, o seguinte link é útil para você: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs Gostei da melhor resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Nessa linha:

```
var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
      url: 'upload.php'
    });
```

Você define a url para a qual deseja enviar o(s) item(ns).

Depois que o form recebe os itens você precisa executar a função: `$scope.uploader.uploadAll()` ou coloca um botão para o usuário fazer isso com o atributo: `ng-click="uploader.uploadAll()"`

É possível fazer upload nos itens individualmente, fazendo um `foreach` no `$scope.uploader.queue` executando a função `upload()` ou um `ng-repeat` na view com um botão para isso.

---

O **Angular File Upload** está marcado como **[ALMOST NOT MAINTAINED]**, por essa razão recomendo usar o [**ng-file-upload**](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)

Qualquer dúvida com ele é só avisar.